# Go to Definition works only for intelliSenseEngine = "Tag Parser" for vscode 1.36 in ubuntu 16.04 VM

Tags: c++, ubuntu-16.04, visual-studio-code

**Environment**

1. Visual Studio Code Version 1.36 for linux vm (ubuntu 16.04 amd64).
2. The extensions I use are C/C++, Bracket Pair Colorizer, Darcula Theme, Remote Fs
3. gcc/g++ version 5.4.0

When I use Goto Definition over a function the vscode goes to the relevant declaration instead.

The c_cpp_properties.json file I use it the following:

```
{

    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Linux",
            "intelliSenseMode":"gcc-x64",
            "compilerPath": "/usr/bin/gcc",
            "includePath": [ "${workspaceFolder}/include"],
            "cppStandard": "c++14",
            "browse": {
                "path": [ "${workspaceFolder}" ],
                "limitSymbolsToIncludedHeaders": true,
                "databaseFilename": ""
            }

        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
```

while the settings file is the following :

```
{
    "C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine" : "Default"
}
```

However when I change the `"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngine" : "Tag Parser"`
the goto definition works fine but Tag Parser uses  use the "fuzzy" IntelliSense engine which is not context aware.
I also added the `"C_Cpp.intelliSenseEngineFallback": "Disabled"` in the settings file but nothing changed.

Does anyone knows what I'm doing wrong here?